# Adding a text title to an image on mouse hover

Tags: css

I would like a bold title to appear on top of an image when the mouse
   hovers over it. This will also be a link.

Comment: Hello on stackoverflow, if you want help here on community please show us your effor, its not place where we create code for you and solve your problem for you. But if you show effort and try to do your issue by your own we are gonna be happy to help you. To start youse google or other search engine to at least start work.

Comment: This is not helpful.

Comment: I'm a very beginner here.  But Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: No problem Damali! just remember on SO if you have an issue we would love to see what you've tried already, your code, and a demo of where you are "stuck" at the moment. It help us help you better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an overlay that gets triggered when the user hovers your image.

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="overlay">
    <span id="text">I'm some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body    {  background:#e7e7e7;}
#box    {  width:300px;
           height:200px;
           box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
          border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
          border-right:2px solid #fff;
          margin:5% auto 0 auto; 
          background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/326221/dummy.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
border-radius:5px;
overflow:hidden;}

#overlay    {  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
               text-align:center;
               padding:60px 0 100px 0;
               opacity:0;
               -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;}

#box:hover #overlay {
               opacity:1;}

#text{
   color:rgba(255,255,255,.85);
   font-size:48px;
   }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/dYxXJa?editors=011)